# Using VS 2013, I am trying to create a simple C++ program, and VARCHAR will not work

Tags: c++, varchar

Using VS 2013, I am trying to create a simple C++ program, and VARCHAR will not work. I have tried declaring a variable as VARCHAR many different ways, and it is always invalid. I used all these includes:

```
#include "windows.h" 
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "direct.h" 
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Yet I still get an error on this line:

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
VARCHAR  emp_name[10];
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

Intellisense: identifier "VARCHAR" is undefined.
```

I have programmed C++ in Visual Studio 6.0, so I am not a dummy to C, just to Visual Studio 2013. Please advise.

Comment: `VARCHAR` doesn't work because it isn't C++.  Are you trying to write SQL code?

Comment: `VARCHAR` is a SQL database data type, not a C++ data type. (It was not a datatype in C++ in Visual Studio either.)

Comment: Indeed.  You are lurching dangerously close to SQL.  Reverse course immediately else you may fall off the edge of the world.

Comment: None of those `#include`s are for C++ either, but for C.

Comment: Please please please please PLEASE go read **any** basic introduction to C++.

Comment: Pro*C/C++ allows you to execute SQL queries inside C/C++ code and save the result of SELECT queries into C/C++ variables. So a "SELECT char_field" statment must be saved into a char[] variable, not VARCHAR. Please note also about a potential problem with zero termination. Depending about how Pro*C/C++ is configured the SELECT statment may return a string zero terminated or not zero terminated!

Answer (score 6):

<sub>*(out on a limb here; your question really doesn't make sense because SQL isn't a part of the C++ language*)...</sub>

It looks like you might have a Pro*C/C++  source file that containes  embedded SQL queries for Oracle.

You need to pre-process such a file with Oracle Pro*C/C++ precompiler in order to get valid C++ source code

See the documentation

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a97269/toc.htm